# How to add information to every span with Spring Cloud Sleuth

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am currently trying to understand how I can customize Spring Cloud Sleuth in a scalable way to add information to every Span.

What I have tried so far:

Using my own implementation of `GenericFilterBean` and `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`, give them a `Tracer` in the constructor and write Tags everytime they are called with `tracer.addTag("key", "value")`

I had a look at the idea of the new baggage information - however I interpret it in a way that it is global for the whole trace - and as the trace has several requests accross different services/machines it would not fit my purpose of adding information on service/machine level.

So far the tags from the Filter and Interceptor get set for some Spans but not for all, when I inspect the JSON that is written to my kafka topic through `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka`

So my question would be: Which types of requests/actions do exist that create spans and what are the appropriate ways to inject something into those spans. As I want to deploy this implementation to several micro services I do not want to annotate each and every method or do similarly work intensive and therefor not scalable approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of such places... but actually, we can tackle the problem from another angle. There's a single place where you can hook in - when the span is closed. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/master/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/SpanReporter.java - you can create your own implementation of `SpanReporter` that before delegating to for example Zipkin span reporter will add a tag. Even easier way will be to just register the `SpanAdjuster` bean that adjusts the span before it gets reported. That way you can add the tag only in one place.

Comment: The `SpanAdjuster` sounds perfect. However, when I try to register a class implementing `SpanAdjuster` it alongside my filter and interceptor in the @Configuration class I get cyclical dependencies because of the tracer I have to inject the constructor of filter and injector. Am I trying it the wrong way? Is there a recommended way to solve this issue?

Comment: I guess you need to show some code. Can you upload it somewhere?

Comment: But tracer is required everywhere and it's s built in another configuration. You don't have a cyclic dependency. Also you can just check if span is exportable and if that's the case just set the tag directly on the span. No need to inject tracer as such then.

Comment: Here is the code: https://codeshare.io/2p6Jx4 - First the configuration class, than my three means of intercepting requests (filter, interceptor, SpanAdjuster) and finally in the end the part of the console output regarding the error message I received.

Comment: Ok now I get it... In places where you have a `BeanFactory` injected you should not inject also a `Tracer`. Retrieve `tracer` like this - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/master/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/web/TraceFilter.java#L404-L409 and try again.

Comment: This solved the issue - strange thing is both Injects were present before adding the SpanAdjuster-Bean. However, only after adding it the issue appeared. Now everything works like a charm and the Spans get their tag. Thank you!